# Is there any right way to print the value of input?

Tags: python

Here I have mentioned a code, where I mentioned input as 56. But I got the value 1 instead of 56.

```
#import pdb
number=int(input("Enter the number to find prime factors:"))
c=[]

for i in range(2,number//2):
    #pdb.set_trace()   
    while(number%i==0):
        #pdb.set_trace()    
        c.append(i)
        number=number//i   
          
print("The prime factors of {} :".format(number), c)
```

Output:

```
Enter the number to find prime factors:56
The prime factors of 1 : [2, 2, 2, 7]
```

Here, I need output like

The prime factors of **56**:

Comment: You keep updating number by dividing it by i...

Comment: you are reassigning `number` in your for-loop, so it is no longer equal to the original number input. make a copy of the original and your code should work

Answer (score 0):

This should solve it. Just create another variable with the same value.

```
#import pdb
numbers=int(input("Enter the number to find prime factors:"))
number=numbers
c=[]

for i in range(2,number//2):
    #pdb.set_trace()   
    while(number%i==0):
        #pdb.set_trace()    
        c.append(i)
        number=number//i   
          
print(f"The prime factors of {numbers} : {c}")
```